# Sequence Proof Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose {$x_n$} is a sequence such that $x_{n+1} - x_n \geq 10^{-6}$ for all $n$. Prove that {$x_n$} is not bounded.

I'm pretty confident that the first step is to show that $x_{n+1} - x_1 \geq n/10^{-6}$ for $n \geq 1$. But I'm not too sure how to show that or how that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x_n=10^{-6}n$, then your "first step" is false.

Comment: my apologies, just edited my mistake in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$x_{n+1}-x_1=(x_2-x_1)+(x_3-x_2)+(x_4-x_3)+\cdots+(x_{n+1}-x_n).\tag{$1$}$$
For note the mass cancellations in $(1)$.

Since $x_{i+1}-x_i\ge 10^{-6}$ for all $i$, it follows that $x_{n+1}\ge x_1+(n)10^{-6}$.

To show that for any given $b$ there is an $n$ such that $x_{n+1}\gt b$, all we need to do is to choose $n$ so that  $x_1+(n)(10^{-6})\gt b$. This will be the case if $n\gt (b-x_1)(10^6)$.

For any real number $u$, there **is** an integer $n$ such that $n+1\gt u$, so we are finished.

**Remark:** The argument boils down to this. The terms grow by at least $10^{-6}$ each time. So after a while they get big, no matter what a lousy start we had, like $x_1=-100000$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Show by induction that $x_{n+1}\ge x_1+10^{-6}n$ for $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent approach is to scale the $x_n$.

Let $y_n = 10^6 x_n$. Then $y_{n+1} - y_n = 10^6 ( x_{n+1}-x_n) \geq 1$. That is, $y_{n+1} \geq y_n +1$ for all $n$.

Hence $y_n \geq y_0 +n$, and so $x_n \geq 10^{-6}(y_0 +n)= x_0 + 10^{-6} n$.